# Database named "Wordpress" present in SSH but missing in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to configure my Linux server to create a staging environment for my Wordpress Multisite.  I am trying to access the wp_options table to be able to make changes, but I'm getting a garbled mess of dashes when I attempt to "SELECT * FROM WP_OPTIONS".

To counter this, I am attempting to use MySQL Workbench to see if it tidies up the mess.  However, while I see the database entitled "wordpress" when I SSH into the server (I'm using Google Cloud Platform as my host), I do NOT see the database when I use MySQL Workbench!

I'm running sudo when activating mysql in SSH, and I'm logging in as "root" when using MySql workbench, so the permissions should be the same.

Below is the comparison between the SSH and what I'm seeing after running a "SHOW DATABASES;" command between them:

[image]

[image]

How can I get the wordpress database to show up in MySQL Workbench???

**Edit 1:** I have ruled out that this is a permissions issue- using SELECT_CURRENTUSER(); I see that I am logged in as the exact same account in both (root@%), so despite having the EXACT same permissions I am getting different tables showing.

Comment: Unless you are doing 'mysql -u root', 'sudo mysql' is not the same as having MySQL workbench authenticate as the MySQL root user, so you haven't ruled out permission issues yet.

Comment: You may use different users with different access rights.

Comment: Doing "mysql -u root" is throwing an access denied notice.  However, as the user root I still can access the other databases via MySQL workbench, so there must be something else here that I'm not catching on to...

Answer (score 3):

You should consider logging in through your root session and then updating your permissions to view the database as the correct user, from whatever server you'd like.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <Database Name>.* TO '<Username>'@'%';
```

Comment: I have tried that on both the CGP SSH and the MySQL Workbench console- doing 'root'@'%' which is what I'm showing as being logged in on in both the SSH and Workbench.  It still doesn't seem to have fixed the issue- and I've tried restarting MySQL Workbench just to check.    Good idea though!

Comment: Update- it seems that if I connect via the computer engine SSH and access mysql the table is visible whereas if I use GCP's Cloud Shell to access mysql it is not.  Interesting...